# How could I make this LINQ query more efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Any suggestions on how to make this LINQ query more efficient? I recently created the formattedDate variable as previously I was calling the GetDateInFormat multiple times.

```
    if (customerOrder.OrderLines
          .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
          .Where(ol => ol.DateTypeId == "OrderPickUpFrom" && ol.ActualDate != null)
          .Any())
    {
        var date = customerOrder.OrderLines
          .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
          .OrderBy(d => d.ActualDate)
          .FirstOrDefault(d => d.DateTypeId == "OrderPickUpFrom" && d.ActualDate != null)
          .ActualDate;

        if (date != null)
        {
            var formattedDate = _dateHelper.GetDateInFormat("DD/MM/YYYY", date);
            order.ArriveDate = formattedDate;
            order.EarliestShipDate = formattedDate;
            order.EarliestDeliveryDate = formattedDate;
            order.EarliestApptTime = _dateHelper.GetDateInFormat("HHMM", date);
        }
    }
```

The customerOrder is a customer Order class.

```
public class Order
{
    public Order();

    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public OrderLine();

    public List<OrderDate> OrderDates { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDate
{
    public OrderDate();

    public DateTimeOffset? ActualDate { get; set; }
    public string DateTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It seems pointless to unpack every `child.OrderLines.OrderDates` just to know if one of them somewhere matches some criteria. `customerOrder.OrderLines.Any(ol => ol.OrderDates.Any(od => od.DateTypeId == "OrderPickUpFrom" && od.ActualDate != null))` can stop as soon as the first qualifying `od` is found, which means the outer `Any` can stop too

Comment: I need to get data from the order line where the DateTypeId is "OrderPickUpFrom".

Comment: If you have MinBy available (morelinq library or .net 6) you could skip a potentially expensive sort in `.OrderBy(d => d.ActualDate)` just to pick the First (minby the data instead). It might be better to just straight hit your data for this item anyway, rather than first checking whether it even exists, as the amount of work to determine existence is potentially the same as finding the item anyway

Comment: Depending on where the data is, it may also not make sense to run a sort before a filter. If you have a millionrows that you order and then exlcude 999,998 of them in the filter, it would have been better to filter first, and then sort two rows, rather than a million. If the data is a DB, and this query is just getting translated, then it may not matter so much, because you're perhaps isolated from this by the translation to SQL, and then the SQL being reinterpreted (forcibly, by natural order of SQL execution) as `WHERE.. ORDER BY`.. Make sure you know how the data is treated

Comment: What version of .net are you using? Do you have MoreLinq installed?

Comment: @CaiusJard .NET 5.0 and no

Comment: Outer if is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

- First of all let's get rid of *two* Linq queries in a row: `Any()` and then `FirstOrDefault`. We can execute just `FirstOrDefault` (or its equivalent) and if we get `null` we'll know that `Any` returns `false`
  (i.e. we have no items).
- Second, with `OrderBy` we sort the *entire* enumerable and then we *drop all* but one item. We are wasting resources. `Aggregate` is more economic way: we have no need to sort but scan the enumeration and return either `null` or smallest `ActualDate`.

**Code:**

```
var date = customerOrder
  .OrderLines
  .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
  .Where(ol => ol.DateTypeId == "OrderPickUpFrom" && ol.ActualDate != null)
  .Select(ol => ol.ActualDate)
  .Aggregate((DateTimeOffset?) null,
     (s, a) => !s.HasValue || s.Value > a ? a : s);

if (date.HasValue) {
  var formattedDate = _dateHelper.GetDateInFormat("DD/MM/YYYY", date);
  
  order.ArriveDate = formattedDate;
  order.EarliestShipDate = formattedDate;
  order.EarliestDeliveryDate = formattedDate;
  order.EarliestApptTime = _dateHelper.GetDateInFormat("HHMM", date);
}
```

Comment: @Bhav, considering the data is actually in a database and likely indexed on ActualDate and DateTypeID, wouldn't it be optimized to sort and just get with Top(1) or Limit 1 at the database level? It is an IQueryable AFAIK. IOW at database level it is not really doing an entire sort but just getting from an index.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I'm reading the data from a JSON file/not a database and I can't guarantee the data will be there.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz: when operating on database level (i.e. executing sql query) I'd rather use `Min` and have either `null` or minimum value. If `IQueryable` creates `order by` + `top(1)` depends on RDBMS, say, Oracle doesn't do it

Comment: Where does it say it was Oracle? Most good backends do that, ie: postgreSQL, SQL server, mySQL... @Bhav, anyway, it was a JSON. Being a JSON, it might also be part of a database like MongoDb or postgreSQL, which is again indexed, we don't know it (and MongoDb would have its own aggregation framework, outside Linq). Min is an aggregation, that might generate a more complex query plan. On the other hand, getting just one record from an index is simple and fast.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko What's the difference between Aggregate and Min from a performance point of view?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can cat your execution time in almost half if you do not call database twice first you call it in the if:

```
customerOrder.OrderLines
            .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
            .Where(ol => ol.DateTypeId == "OrderPickUpFrom" && ol.ActualDate != null).Any())
```

and than in true branch:

```
var date = customerOrder.OrderLines
                                .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
                                .OrderBy(d => d.ActualDate)
                                .FirstOrDefault(d => d.DateTypeId == "OrderPickUpFrom" && d.ActualDate != null).ActualDate;
```

if you look at those they are virtually identical you can achieve same result using this:

```
var date = customerOrder.OrderLines
                                .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
                                .OrderBy(d => d.ActualDate)
                                .Where(d => d.DateTypeId == "OrderPickUpFrom" && d.ActualDate != null)
.Select(x => x.ActualDate)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

now null value in date will serve you as bases for the if statement

```
if(date != null) {

   // do your stuff
}
```

Other than this you can create an index on the database that covers your query so containing DataTypeId and ActualDate.

Comment: *if you do not call database twice* - it's a bit of an assumption that there even is one, by the way

Comment: no there is no assumption; in the query you filter out possibility of null so you will not get null value as a valid result. So having null in result is equivalent with no matching record.

Comment: It's not a database. I'm reading from a file. :)

Comment: ok so making it single pass read is your best bet, and you should use the aggregate suggestion from Dmitry to not sort the full thing and only get the lowest value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `.SelectMany()`, `.Where()` and `.Min()` as follows:

```
var date = customerOrder.OrderLines
    .SelectMany(ol => ol.OrderDates)
    .Where(ol => ol.DateTypeId == "OrderPickUpFrom")
    .Min(ol => ol.ActualDate);
```

`.Min()` will return `null` when the result from `.Where()` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a `customerOrder`. This customerOrder has zero or more `OrderLines`. Every OrderLine has zero or more `OrderDates`.

From the CustomerOrder you are only interested in all `OrderDates`. The rest of the Order or the OrderLines are not interesting for you.

Every OrderDate has property `DateTypeId` and `ActualDate`. From all OrderDates that are mentioned deep inside this customerOrder, you want to see if there is at least one OrderDate that has a value for property DateTypeId that equals "OrderPickUpFrom" AND a value for property ActualDate that is not null.

You don't define what you want if no OrderDate matches at all.

If one of these OrderDate matches this requirement, you take the ActualDate of the oldest matching OrderDate, or null if there is no matching OrderDate

> You used `Any()` to check that there is at least one OrderDate that has a value for property DateTypeId that equals "OrderPickUpFrom" AND a value for property ActualDate that is not null. Therefore you know that there is at least one matching OrderDate, and thus at least one matching ActualDate. Therefore you know that `date` is never null.

```
const string requiredDateTypeId = "OrderPickupFrom";
var date = customerOrder.OrderLines
    .SelectMany(orderLine => orderline.OrderDate)
    .Where(orderDate => orderDate.DateTypeId == requiredDateTypeId
                     && orderDate.ActualDate != null)

    .OrderBy(orderDate => orderDate.ActualDate)
    .Select(orderDate => orderDate.ActualDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In words:

- From the customerOrder, make one big sequence of all OrderDates that are in all OrderLines of this customerOrder.
- Keep only those OrderDates that have a value for property DateTypeId that equals the required DateTypeId AND that have a non-null value for ActualDate.
- Sort the remaining OrderDates by ascending value of ActualDate. So the OrderDate with the oldest ActualDate is first
- From the sorted OrderDates, select the value of property ActualDate
- Keep the first one, or null if there issn't any OrderDate that has the required values.

  if (date != null)
  {
  var formattedDate = etc.

Now there is one thing you can do to make the LINQ more efficient: why sort all OrderDates if you only plan to use the one that has the oldest value for ActualDate. In other words: if you found the oldest one, you don't need to sort any of the OrderDates that came after the oldest one. In fact, you'd like to have some `Min` function, where you can define the property on which to find the minimum one.

For this I use an extension method. If you are not familiar with extension methods, read [Extension Methods demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp)

```
public static MinOrDefault<T, TProperty> Min(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TProperty> propertySelector)
{
    return MinOrDefault(source, propertySelector, null);
}

public static MinOrDefault<T, TProperty> Min(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TProperty> propertySelector,
    IComparer<TProperty> comparer)
{
    // TODO: check source and propertySelector not null
    if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<TProperty>.Default;

    
    using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            // There is at least one element in source
            T minValue = enumerator.Current;
            TProperty minPropertyValue = propertySelector(minValue);

            // check the rest of the sequence
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // there is a next. Is the property smaller?
                T value = enumerator.Current;
                TProperty propertyValue = propertySelector(value);
                if (comparer.Compare(propertyValue, minPropertyValue) < 0)
                {
                    // propertyValue is smaller than minPropertyValue
                    minValue = value;
                    minPropertyValue = propertyValue;
                }
                // else: minValue is still the smallest; do nothing
            }

            // if here, enumerated to the end of the sequence
            return minValue;
        }
        else
        {
             // empty sequence, return default:
             return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Your code will be:

```
OrderDate oldestOrderDate = customerOrder.OrderLines
    .SelectMany(orderLine => orderline.OrderDate)
    .Where(orderDate => orderDate.DateTypeId == requiredDateTypeId
                     && orderDate.ActualDate != null)
    .MinOrDefault(orderDate => orderDate.ActualDate);

if (oldestOrderDate != null)
{
    etc.
```